# Brick Wall Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

I am doing this problem on SingPath -

> We want to make a row of bricks that is exactly goal inches long. We have a number of small bricks (1 inch each) and big bricks (5 inches each). Return True if it is possible to make the goal by choosing from the given bricks. This is a little harder than it looks and can be done without any loops.

So, I wrote this simple code, which works for all the conditions but except for one -

```
def make_bricks(small,big,goal):
    if (small + big * 5) >= goal:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

It doesn't work for this condition - `make_bricks(2, 4, 13)` my code returns a `True`, but the expected output is `False`.

Which makes sense, but not really sure how to translate that into code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have your calculations wrong; you need to see if *some* of the big and small bricks can be used to the required row; you are only determining if the bricks given can produce a row *at least* that long.

You cannot build a row of length 13, because you don't have enough small bricks; with two large bricks you'd need another 3 small.

You need to see how many brick of size 5 you'd need, and add to that the remainder in small bricks. Take into account that 1 large brick and 8 small ones would work equally well as 2 large bricks and 3 small ones!

First calculate how many big bricks are needed, but take the actual value of big bricks you have if you have fewer than you'd ideally use, then see if the remainder of the goal can be handled in small bricks:

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
    big_bricks = min(goal // 5, big)
    remainder = goal - (big_bricks * 5)
    return remainder <= small
```

`//` is integer division, `13 // 5` is `2`, so you'd use at most 2 of the large bricks. The remainder then is `3`, but you only have the two small bricks so the result is `False`:

```
>>> make_bricks(2, 4, 13)
False
>>> make_bricks(3, 4, 13)
True
>>> make_bricks(8, 1, 13)
True
```

Comment: Love the explanation! I get it now. One more question, how to develop algorithmic thinking liking you? Is it just lot of practice & experience over the years?

Comment: Experience, but [this MIT lecture series](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/) helped.